# Send values from HTML Form to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, xhtml

How do I link the PHP to the HTML form? I understand how to do the PHP and how to do the HTML, but how do I link the php to the html or is that automatic,

how does the HTML form know about the PHP?

Comment: This concept is very fundamental and always explained in any introductory PHP book, where you can get a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hello. please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp for more information on php with specific instructions on the left hand side nav bar.

Answer (score 3):

In your form set the action attribute to the path of your php script eg:

```
<form action="/path/to/php/script.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was much appreciated, credit to you

Answer (score 2):

You set your action="" in your form to point to your PHP script. When the user clicks the submit button in your form, the PHP script will be called and the formdata will be handed over to the PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

The method you choose when making your form is how PHP will gather the values passed in.

As such:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
<!-- OR -->
<form action="handler.php" method="get">
```

The `action` tells where the form values will be sent to and the `method` tells how the values of the items in the form will be passed back to the server. The `post` method will send the values back so they may be retrieved by the `$_POST` array (both `post` and `get` can be retrieved by the `$_REQUEST` array). For example:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput">
```

Will post back to the server and can be retrieved by

```
$var = $_POST['myInput'];
```

It's always best to test if there is actually an input, and the following can be used

```
if(isset($_POST['myInput'])) { /*do something if set*/}
else{ /*do something if not set*/}
```

If the form was submitted by the `get` method, the values of the form is passed back in the URL, like such:

```
http://www.domain.tld/handler.php?myInput=someValue
```

The value is then retrieved by using the `$_GET` array:

```
$var = $_GET['myInput'];
```

Once again, you should test that it exists.

For good examples and explanations, please read a PHP book or search for PHP and HTML forms. This is the very basics of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a php file

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" value="html form data" name="name" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  echo 'I am php. I know this value is from html - '. $_POST['name'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about refilling your form with the php values: inside your input fields, just add the request variable.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value="<?=$_REQUEST['var_name']?>" />
```

If you are talking about sending date to php, just point to a file using the form action.

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">

</form>
```

Then you process all the data in that php file.